# getting NullPointerException in getApplicationContext()

Tags: android, applicationcontext

I am getting a Nullpointer exception when I open my app and this was on the background. My onResume calls an Asyntask which calls this method:

```
public boolean reloadIni() throws NetworkConnetionException {
   if(mMyApp == null)//chek if the object has been deleted by the gc.
   {
     Log.d(TAG,"task mMyApp is null, initialize mMyApp");
     mMyApp = (MyApp) getApplicationContext();          
   }
   User userLogin = mMyApp.getUserLogin();  
  //....more stuff
}
```

But as you can see I am cheking if my variable mMyApp is != null. Is it possible that getApplicationContext() returns null?

Comment: Did you point to your application class in the <Application> node of your Manifest file? `<application android:name=".MyApp" ...`

Comment: Yes i did. it works fine while is open the app, but seems like the gc close that varible to save memory when I switch the app to 2nd plane.
<application android:name="MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/icoapp" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

Comment: As long as the activity is created getApplicationContext should not return null.

Comment: What happens if you call getApplicationContext() from within onResume()?

Comment: I also do it there, but keep getting that wonderful NullPointerException :(  @Override
 protected void onResume() { 
  super.onResume();
  Log.d(TAG, "ActivityIni onResume, execute task");
  if(mMyApp == null)
   mMyApp = (MyApp)getApplicationContext();  
  mIniTask = new IniTask();
  mIniTask.execute(""); 
 }

Comment: Did you by any chance instantiate the activity class like a normal class instead of starting it as the main activity or by calling it from another activity? That's the only reason you would get a NullPointerException here

Comment: I bet the NPE is in `mMyApp = (MyApp) getApplicationContext();` - post more of your code in your question not in comments - where you call the `reloadIni` ? In the constructor of the AsyncTask maybe ?